# Table with calculated column

Tags: magento-1.7, database, mysql-triggers

If I'd like to have a table with three columns:

- `firstname`,
- `lastname` and
- `username` (a combination of `firstname` and `lastname`)

I'd like the table to auto generate the username as soon as a record is inserted with a first & lastname.

**Please note that I would like it to do so in an automated fashion, without the use of a cronjob or something as such.**

How can I set this up efficiently? From what I understand MySQL does not support declarative computed fields.

According to this page:  [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 18 Stored Programs and Views :: 18.3 Using Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

- > MySQL triggers activate only for changes made to tables by SQL statements. They do not activate for changes in tables made by APIs that do not transmit SQL statements to the MySQL Server; in particular, they are not activated by updates made using the NDB API

I am using version 5.0.95 which should support triggers. Do you think Magento's ORM will be compatible with this?

Comment: Could you please explain why do you need this because, I don't understand the purpose of your third field. As combining first two you can always get third one.

Comment: I'd prefer not to implement additional logic throughout an existing system covering a very large database, this scaled down version of the scenario accurately describes the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Since EE 1.13 and CE 1.8 Magento uses SQL triggers itself for real-time indexing. So they already work with the Magento ORM.

> According to this page:  [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 18 Stored
>   Programs and Views :: 18.3 Using Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)
>
> - > MySQL triggers activate only for changes made to tables by SQL statements. They do not activate for changes in tables made by APIs
>   >     that do not transmit SQL statements to the MySQL Server; in
>   >     particular, they are not activated by updates made using the NDB API
>
> I am using version 5.0.95 which should support triggers. Do you think
>   Magento's ORM will be compatible with this?

Creating your own triggers works well **independent of the Magento version**. Magento's ORM only makes changes with normal SQL statements so the quoted issue does not apply.

Comment: does 1.7.x and below support SQL triggers?